# Allow only A-I 0-9 and the symbols $# (RegEX)

Tags: c#, regex

I`m currently working on a student project in C#, and I want to check if a string contains only the following characters:

A-I
0-9
$
#

The original string:

```
string rawData ="$A008B20130503C103804D00000000E1022F0080G0128H022I022#";
```

My code is as follows:

```
string regEXstring = @"^[A-I0-9$#]+$";
Regex regex = new Regex(regEXstring);
if (regex.IsMatch(rawData))
   {
       dataOK = true;
   }
   else
       dataOK = false;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify what you think is going wrong? I've just tested that code and at a glance it seems to work (assuming that `rawdata`/`rawData` is just a typo and that you have declared dataOK somewhere).

Comment: This is matching.. You know `rawdata` and `rawData` are different right?

Comment: You can also replace the `if` with `dataOK = regexIsMatch(rawData);` (or rawdata, whichever is correct)

Comment: Thank you for fast replies. I realized that the string actually starts with NEWLN CR... This is probably whats causing the trouble..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing your `rawdata`/`rawData` typo, the code works fine. The `dataOK` variable becomes `true` with your example data, and `false` if one adds other characters to the string.

Judging from your example data, you can improve the verification so that you can also determinte that:

- the string starts with $
- the string ends with #
- the strings contains entities that consist of a single character followed by at least three digits

For that, use a pattern like:

```
string regEXstring = @"^\$([A-I]\d{3,})+#$";
```

Comment: Thank you for a better RegEx string.
I just realised that the string from the card (sendt via RS-232) starts with NEWLN CR.

Is this whats causing the trouble?


The rawdata/rawData was just a typo here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @EivindFrøystad: Yes, additional newline characters would make the pattern fail. You can add `[\r\n]*` at the beginning of the pattern to allow newline characters there, e.g. `"^[\r\n]*\$([A-I]\d{3,})+#$"`. Alternatively you could use `rawData = rawData.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n","");` to remove any newline characters in the string before verifying.

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful answer! I fixed it with rawData.Trim();